# EC2 starcluster stopped working

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, starcluster

Starcluster on EC2 ubuntu stopped working. I am not aware of any intentional configuration change or anything else and am unable to find much help. Can you please tell me if anyone has any suggestions? starting, terminating, or even listing clusters is erroring out. Below is the error I am getting when I try to listclusters:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-29-249-203:~$ starcluster listclusters
StarCluster - (http://star.mit.edu/cluster) (v. 0.94)
Software Tools for Academics and Researchers (STAR)
Please submit bug reports to starcluster@mit.edu

---------------------------------
revcls (security group: @sc-revcls)
---------------------------------
!!! ERROR - Unhandled exception occured
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/cli.py", line 274, in main
    sc.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/commands/listclusters.py", line 36, in execute
    show_ssh_status=self.opts.show_ssh_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/cluster.py", line 290, in list_clusters
    nodes = cl.nodes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/cluster.py", line 720, in nodes
    if n.is_master():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/node.py", line 883, in is_master
    return self.alias == "master"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/StarCluster-0.94-py2.7.egg/starcluster/node.py", line 139, in alias
    aliases = aliasestxt.splitlines()[2:]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

!!! ERROR - Oops! Looks like you've found a bug in StarCluster
!!! ERROR - Crash report written to: /home/ubuntu/.starcluster/logs/crash-report-1183.txt
!!! ERROR - Please remove any sensitive data from the crash report
!!! ERROR - and submit it to starcluster@mit.edu
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of StarCluster are you using? Is it the latest release or the latest dev version?

If I look at your error on the latest dev version, it refers to this line:

https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/blob/5442e91e159acca48b645f5ddf629d65c59cd7e0/starcluster/node.py#L139

My guess is that you are having an issue with your cluster alias tags. In any cases, it's very strange that even terminating the cluster and starting a new one doesn't solve the issue.

If you find anything more, can reproduce the issue or need more help, you may also use StarCluster mailing list. http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/starcluster